CMake error when building exe with pyinstaller in visual studio 2019
I am building an exe with pysinstaller and everytime I run the command it builds, but visual studio is throwing some warnings/errors at me.
my pyinstaller command:
pyinstaller --onedir --add-data "config.json;." file.py

The warnings include:
CMake Warning (dev) in C:\Users\...\dist\...\CMakeLists.txt:
1> [CMake]   No project() command is present.  The top-level CMakeLists.txt file must
1> [CMake]   contain a literal, direct call to the project() command.  Add a line of
1> [CMake]   code such as
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]     project(ProjectName)
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   near the top of the file, but after cmake_minimum_required().
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   CMake is pretending there is a "project(Project)" command on the first
1> [CMake]   line.

CMake Warning in C:\Users\...\dist\...\CMakeLists.txt:
1> [CMake]   The object file directory
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]     C:/Users/.../dist/.../x64-Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles/cmTC_05bd2.dir/./
and            C:/Users/.../dist/.../x64-Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles/cmTC_26db5.dir/./
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   has 231 characters.  The maximum full path to an object file is 250
1> [CMake]   characters (see CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX).  Object file
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]     CMakeCCompilerABI.c.obj
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   cannot be safely placed under this directory.  The build may not work
1> [CMake]   correctly.

CMake Error at C:\Users\...\dist\...\CMakeLists.txt:18 (arrow_install_all_headers):
1> [CMake]   Unknown CMake command "arrow_install_all_headers".
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] CMake Warning (dev) in C:\Users\...\dist\...\MakeLists.txt:
1> [CMake]   No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]     cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
1> [CMake]   if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
1> [CMake]   information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".

Now, when I run the exe it works perfectly fine. How can I get rid of these warnings?

If you are building a CMake project written by someone else, then the warning No project() command is present usually means that you choose wrong directory as a source one. In a CMake project multiple directories may have file CMakeLists.txt, but usually only one of such directories is intended to be the top-level one, which you pass to cmake as a source directory. The error Unknown CMake command usually signals about the same problem: You have specified for cmake a source directory, which is not intended to be the source one.

@Tsyvarev how would I choose the correct source one then?

Read a project's documentation. Usually it states, which directory should be the source one. Sometimes they provide instructions for building a project; in that case you may deduce the source directory from the parameters of cmake command.

I created a python script and am creating an exe from it, so the project is mine. When i build the exe from my script that is when I get all the warnings. TBH I have never even heard of a cmake project until now so excuse my ignorance. I can update my question with my folder structure and exactly what I do to make the exe and see if that aligns with what you previously mentioned.  @Tsyvarev

You may run pyinstaller from the command line. How Visual Studio is ever related to that? It smells like instead of (or in addition to) running pyinstaller your are trying to build some CMake project.
